# typeid as a specialize template argument in VS2012 causes code analysis to fail

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, typeid

I have a legacy ORM that marries a class to a database and it compiles fine under VS2008 and VS2012.  I tried using the VS2012 Code Analysis's feature and it gives me compile errors C2975 and C2440.  I've pulled the relevant code out to help isolate the issue:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

typedef std::vector<unsigned char>  byte_packet;


// RTTI option (/GR) required
template<const std::type_info &ref_type_info> struct _TypeOf { /* blank to cause compile error for unsupported types */ };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(std::string)>  { typedef std::string typed; };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(int)>          { typedef int typed; };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(unsigned int)> { typedef unsigned int typed; };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(double)>       { typedef double typed; };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(byte_packet)>  { typedef byte_packet typed; };
template<> struct _TypeOf<typeid(time_t)>       { typedef time_t typed; };

#define TYPEOF(x) _TypeOf<typeid(x)>::typed


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    TYPEOF(i) j;

    j = i;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following pair of errors for each template<> line:

```
error C2975: 'ref_type_info' : invalid template argument for '_TypeOf', expected compile-time constant expression
error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const type_info &'
```

It appears the compiler treats the typeid<...> as an int argument for the template.  The TYPEOF() macro is used to declare a new variable of the same type as the macro's argument.  This macro is embedded in other macros and I am open to alternative/better ways to do this.  It does work as-is but VS2012's Code Analysis feature chokes and I don't know why.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you just use `auto j = i`? Or if you have to keep the `TYPEOF` macro, `#define TYPEOF(x) decltype(x)`?

Comment: Spot on.  Thanks.  I never heard of decltype since I just recently migrated from VS2008 to VS2012.  Changing TYPEOF(x) to be decltype(x) was the trick.  Much cleaner.  TYPEOF was used inside other macros and templates and this was the easiest, least-intrusive change.